# Handling WM_APPCOMMAND (volume control)

Tags: c#, winapi, volume, windows-shell

How do I handle WM_APPCOMMAND messages to increase volume in a custom shell? I have tried waveOutSetVolume and it doesnt not work. I tried the IAudioEndpointVolume interface and this works only inside Windows explorer shell, doesnt work in custom shell. Could anyone suggest me how to go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control

The above article helped me solve my problem